# Same permissions, different rights?

Tags: python, linux, apache, permissions, selinux

I am running a Python script within an Apache server through CGI. Inside the script I try to read files that reside inside /home directory. However, I can read one file and not the other. This is very frustrating to my goal of understanding permissions and what can be read or not.

```
# Works
file_tmp = open("/home/blastdbs/db_01.fasta", 'r')

# Fails
file_tmp = open("/home/blast_dbs/db_01.fasta", 'r')
<type 'exceptions.IOError'>: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/blast_dbs/db_01.fasta' 

ls -l /home/
drwxr-xr-x.  2 myself myself  4096 Jun 17 18:18 blastdbs
drwxr-xr-x.  2 myself myself  4096 Jun 17 18:18 blast_dbs

ls -l /home/blastdbs/
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 myself myself   32484551 Jun 17 17:28 db_01.fasta
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 myself myself 2279012809 Jun 17 13:10 db_02.fasta

ls -l /home/blast_dbs/
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 myself myself  32484551 Jun 17 13:09 db_01.fasta
```

By the way, trying to read db_02 yields the same exception.

I hope someone could bring some light on this.
Thank you

Comment: by the way, when running the script standalone it works nicely. So apache environment or python cgi module should be involved on this strange (to my knowledge) behaviour.

Comment: To see where can it be failing: What if you copy `db_01.fasta` from blastdbs (the one working) to blast_dbs (the one not working)?

Comment: `cp blastdbs/db_01.fasta blast_dbs/` --> _<type 'exceptions.IOError'>: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/blast_dbs/db_01.fasta'_ The standalone script keeps working.

Comment: @cantalapiedra Have you checked if there's anything on Apache log? Your script should be executed as a different user, but as both files are readable by anyone the problem should be other.

Comment: How do you know the "rights" are the same?  There's a trailing period on the last x, which means there are SOME acls set - those may well be different.

Comment: @salem the Apache log shows the exception above, if that is the log you refer to.

Comment: I have checked ACL entries with getfacl, and both directories and files have the same permissions, and don't seem to have extended ACLs.

Comment: In fact "Turns out, the mkfs commands have been modified to set ACLs on by default, and the dot is a place holder to represent an empty ACL. " from [dougbunger.blogspot.com.es](http://dougbunger.blogspot.com.es/2011/02/mysterious-linux-permission-dots.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache server is installed within a Linux distribution with SELinux enabled. SELinux by default denies Apache to read files in /home folders. By using ls -Z one can check SELinux labels of files. In my case, while usual (DAC) permissions were the same and there were no ACLs set, SELinux context was different:

Next one is readable from Apache daemon and scripts:

```
unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:
```

Next one is the file that SELinux denies access to Apache:

```
unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following insturctions but with httpd_sys_content_t for labeling your directory. Do not label the whole home directory, but just for example /home/myuser/apache

https://superuser.com/questions/607409/configuring-selinux-to-allow-logging-to-a-file-thats-outside-var-log